# Widget is always repaint although I used ValueNotifier

Tags: flutter

In a Flutter application utilizing ValueNotifier to manage state, I've observed that despite only a portion of the UI needing to be updated upon state change, the entire widget tree gets repainted. This behavior can be visually seen with the debugRepaintRainbowEnabled tool enabled, where the entire widget tree is highlighted upon state changes. I've included code snippets and before-after screenshots for reference.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  debugRepaintRainbowEnabled = true;

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final ValueNotifier<int> _counter = ValueNotifier(0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: _counter,
          builder: (context, value, _) {
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text(
                    'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '$value',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _counter.value++;
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

[Previous value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ove5G.png)
[After change value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugmrq.png)

I'd like to understand:

1. Is this behavior normal in Flutter?
2. What could be the underlying cause for the entire widget tree to repaint despite using ValueNotifier?
3. Does this behavior have any potential impact on application performance or should it be a concern for optimization?

Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This is because of IconButton's splash which is causing the repaint of all widgets if you try `GestureDetector` you can see that the extra paint is gone and also only wrap text widget in `ValueListenableBuilder` so only the text widget will be rebuilt.

Comment: I used GestureDetector but it still repaint all the screen

Comment: `ValueListenableBuilder` prevents from building your entire UI - this is different from (re)painting which is very cheap and does not use much CPU / resources

Comment: Like the docs saild: "Show borders that change color when elements repaint. Useful for finding unnecessary repaints."
Then if i don't know why widget is repaint then how can i know what widget is unnecessary repaints.

Comment: you don't have to worry about any repaints unless you have some widgets that are expensive in repainting (for example custom painters that draw thousands of lines, points etc) - in such cases use `RepaintBoundary` as a parent